# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'some_xyz_method' was never awaited

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

Inside Method 1 I want try block to get executed first then want the call_ordercreate method to be executed , Tried with asyncio but getting error output as seen in description , how can I fix this issue?

Method #1

```
@app.route("/slack/message_actions", methods=[ "POST" ])
def message_actions():

        if (payload[ "type" ] == "view_submission" and payload[ "view" ][ "callback_id" ] == "sthpush"):
            print("entered push")
            call_ordercreate(thread_ts, user_name)  **# Run this method after executing try block** 
            try:
                return jsonify(
                    {
                        "response_action": "push",
                        "view": orderwaitmessage,
                    }
                )
            except SlackApiError as e:
                code = e.response[ "error" ]
                return make_response(f"Failed to open a modal due to {code}", 200)
```

Method #2

```
async def call_ordercreate(thread_ts, user_name):
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    url_list1 = CONST_ORDERCREATE_API  
    r = requests.get(url)
```

Error Output

```
C:/Users/PycharmProjects/iptautobot-events/newapp.py:263: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'call_ordercreate' was never awaited
call_ordercreate(thread_ts, user_name)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to call an asynchronous function from a normal synchronised function. You should use the [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) method to run that function. This would not raise that `RuntimeWarning`. So your code will look like this:

```py
@app.route("/slack/message_actions", methods=[ "POST" ])
def message_actions():

        if (payload[ "type" ] == "view_submission" and payload[ "view" ][ "callback_id" ] == "sthpush"):
            print("entered push")
            asyncio.run(call_ordercreate(thread_ts, user_name))
            try:
                return jsonify(
                    {
                        "response_action": "push",
                        "view": orderwaitmessage,
                    }
                )
            except SlackApiError as e:
                code = e.response[ "error" ]
                return make_response(f"Failed to open a modal due to {code}", 200)
```

However, it seems that you want to run `call_ordercreate` after returning response back to user. I am afraid that's not possible as the whole request context gets destroyed once you `return`. Moreover, flask (I am assuming its flask) is a WSGI server which means it handles requests in a synchronous way. That's why using `asyncio.run` is the only way to call your asynchronous functions. The downside? It *waits* for the task to complete, which is definitely not what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for explaining any alternative to fix this issue?